# Problem using NestJS with TypeOrm to connect in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using NestJS with TypeOrm to connect in MySQL but returns an error: 'No repository for "User" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in the current "default" connection?'

Without TypeOrm, I can run the server.

"User" is my entity.

**app.module**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            type: 'mysql',
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3306,
            username: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'myserver',
            entities: [`${__dirname}/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}`],
            synchronize: true,
            logging: true
        }),
        UserModule
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(
        private connection: Connection,
    ) { }
}
```

**user.module**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
            User,
        ]),
    ],
    providers: [
        UserService,
    ],
    controllers: [
        UserController,
    ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

**user.entity**

```
@Entity('user')
export class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column()
    name?: string;
    @Column({ name: 'last_name' })
    lastName?: string;

    @Column({ default: false })
    active?: boolean;
}
```

Can someone tell me, please, what's wrong?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved moving TypeOrm config to another file. See below:

**app.module**

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
        UserModule
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(
        private connection: Connection,
    ) { }
}
```

**ormconfig.json**

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "root",
    "password": "",
    "database": "myserver",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": true,
    "autoLoadEntities": true,
    "entities": ["./src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}", "./dist/**/*.entity.js"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was have this problem with sqlite database and i have tried a lot of solutions untill i found the right solution
1- ensure that the entity is the same structure this

```
`import{Entity,Column
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn}from 
 'typeorm'
 @Entity()
 export class User {
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
 id : number ;
 @Column()
 email : string ;
 @Column()
 password : string
`
```

2-ensure the Root Module

```
` @Module({

 imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
 type : 'sqlite',
 database : 'db.sqlite',
 entities :[User],
 synchronize : true ,

 }),UsersModule],

 controllers: [AppController],
 providers: [AppService],
 })
 export class AppModule {}`
```

Comment: It will be good if you post how did you do before works. To anyone see